# system.time command - diffrence?

Tags: r

When I run this command:

```
system.time(fread('x.csv', header = T))
```

I receive this output:

```
user   system  elapsed 
4.740  0.048   4.785
```

In simple terms, what does each of those means, besides "elapsed," which the time that has passed since running the command? What do User and System mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/timing_code.htm

> The values presented (**user**, **system**, and **elapsed**) will be defined by your operating system, but generally, the **user** time relates to the execution of the code, the **system** time relates to your CPU, and the **elapsed** time is the difference in times since you started the stopwatch (and will be equal to the sum of user and system times if the chunk of code was run altogether). While the difference of .42 seconds may not seem like much, this gain in efficiency is huge!